# How to parse and display contents of WCF in android?

Tags: android, wcf, xml-parsing

hi m using a web service.
i m doing for a POC. 
here is my activity class:
i m using ksoap2.

```
package ab.tina;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TinaWebActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView txtview;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        txtview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        try {
            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject("http://www.webserviceX.NET/", "GetQuote");
            Request.addProperty("symbol", "MFST");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);


            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx");


            Log.e("tag1","err1");
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetQuote", envelope);
            Log.e("tag2","err2");

            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            Log.e("tag3","err3");
           //String str=(String)response.getProperty(1);
            txtview.setText(response.toString());
            //txtview.setText(response.toString());
            Log.e("tag4","err4");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e("tag5","err5");
            txtview.setText(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

i m getting result like this:

```
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
<StockQuotes><Stock><Symbol>MFST</Symbol><Last>0.00</Last><Date>N/A</Date><Time>N/A</Time><Change>N/A</Change><Open>N/A</Open><High>N/A</High><Low>N/A</Low><Volume>N/A</Volume><MktCap>N/A</MktCap><PreviousClose>N/A</PreviousClose><PercentageChange>N/A</PercentageChange><AnnRange>N/A - N/A</AnnRange><Earns>N/A</Earns><P-E>N/A</P-E><Name>MFST</Name></Stock></StockQuotes>
</string>
```

please tell me how can i parse it . which class i will require and wht method should i use?

Comment: check these out, might help: http://www.kevingao.net/wcf-java-interop and http://www.kevingao.net/wcf-java-interop/java-client-and-wcf-server.html or http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/glassfish/ProjectTango/  - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/4c5d88fb-5427-4024-aef1-94b601745dd1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if you want to get info from that you need to search inside of soapobject each node is a soapobject.

in your case you do something like:

```
 resultData = (SoapObject)resultData.resultData.getProperty("StockQuotes");
//now resultData have all node of stockQuotes
 resultData = (SoapObject)resultData.resultData.getProperty("Stock");
//now resultdata have stock 

//now to parse string saftelly go to ksoap 2 android project download last version 
String symbol = resulresultData.getPropertySafelyAsString("Symbol", "NO DATA");
//or
String symbol = resulresultData.getPropertySafelyAsString("Symbol");

//and so on for other XML
```

have fun happy coding

Comment: If you can't do it tell me i'll be glad to help

Comment: http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html